# Why is this a Concatenation Error? Just Can't Figure It Out

Tags: concatenation, string-concatenation

My code is here: https://pastebin.com/UxZibL4B

This simple gaming program is what I am using to learn to code. It will, eventually, manage all of the tasks for an old school version of dungeons and dragons. I'd like it to be able to handle all of the referee functions for the game.

Here is the offending line:

```
Palanquin_v                     = ['ATTRIBUTES ', '^ ', 0, 'S ', 0, 'F ', 0, 'C ', 1, 'U ', 0, 'X ', 0, '£ ', 0, 'T ', 0, 'ARMOR CLASS ', 12, 'HIT DICE ', 3, 'D8', 1, 'D6', 0, 'D4', 0, 'D10', 0, 'D12', 0, 'DAMAGE ', '1d8',                            0,                                    0,                   0,    0, 'SPECIAL ', 'Roll encounter each turn,  which aids palanquin if given 1,000 GP. Buys gems at 2d6 x 10% value; insulted if refused.',   'MOVE ', 12, 'FLIGHT ', 0, 'SWIM ',  0,  'Palanquin'] # got a traceback to here, traceback was 288, then 240 and variable printed was Monster_Generator_Roll_v, with a value of 89
```

For now, all it does is "roll up" random monster encounters from a specified list. Each of the monsters is given a number of stats (most of which are presently incomprehensible, I'm trying to get it to work before I pretty-it-up).

However, there are two "rolls" that can modify the stats of the monsters:

A monster can be "Sorcerous" meaning the it knows how to cast spells, which are also generated randomly from a list.

A monster can also be "Tremendous" meaning it is just bigger and meaner than most monsters of its type. When this result is generated, the creature's armor class, hit dice and damage per attack (across multiple attacks, if it can make more than one) are all increased by +4.

Any monster can, again, randomly, get multiple additions of both the "Sorcerous" and "Tremendous" results. Thus, a "Sorcerous, Sorcerous, Tremendous, Tremendous,Tremendous, Vampire" (extremely uncommon, but it could occur) would get the additional "Sorcerous" increase twice, and the "Tremendous", increase three times.

By and large it works pretty well, but it is giving me a concatenation error (can only concatenate int to int, not int to string) when it hits line number 89, which contains the stats for the Palanquin monster.

Though this is a laid out exactly like every other line of code, for some reason, the concatenation error arises only when the "Tremendous" roll takes place. When python tries to give the numeric +4 boost to the monster's armor class, it tells me that I am trying to concatenate an integer to a string.

I don't understand this, as it looks like a string in the code, every other monster armor class is treated the same way, and notepad++ is displaying the stat in red, which is what it does for integers on my computer.

Like a good little programmer, I've been going over this for days, looking it up on stack overflow, youtube, reddit, etc., and just can't figure it out.

I'm sure its something simple.

Any help?

Thanks.

BTW: I'm brand new to programming, and to stackoverflow, and I'm sure I'm breaking a dozen rules, but none intentionally.  Your patience is appreciated.

PS The code is in a loop simply because it was easier for me to try to debug if it broke quickly. Again, I hope I'm not breaking any rules.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a print statement just before the addition, I see a **:

```
103
Tremendous
89
Black Knight
>>>>> ** 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DnD.py", line 295, in <module>
    Add_Tremendous_To_Random_Monster_f()
  File "DnD.py", line 247, in Add_Tremendous_To_Random_Monster_f
    Tremendous_Monster_ARMOR_CLASS_v = (Randomly_Generated_Monster_v[18] + (Tremendous_Monster_Bonus_v))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

If I check the Black Knight (line 163), I see:

```
'ARMOR CLASS ','**'
```

The concatenate fails because of the **. It is expecting a number.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Mike.  I don't understand it though, previously, it was breaking on Palanquin. Still, I'm very much obliged.